# Remove single quote

Tags: sas

I have a column called `rea`. Inside, there are data like below

```
oc'ean
```

I'm using the function `tranwrd` to remove the `'`

```
tranwrd(rea,'''','');
```

Can I use something else than the `''''` to represent the `'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can quote single-quotes within double-quotes, and vice versa.

```
tranwrd(rea,"'",'');
```

But if you just wish to remove the quotes, rather than replace them with a non-space character, use the `compress` function

```
compress(rea,"'");
```

Comment: Cheers Chris for your answer.